# Law of refelction for electron-metal interactions?

Tags: x-rays, imaging, medical-physics

I was reading 'Webb's Physics of Medical Imaging' which had a diagram very similar to the following in it: 
[image: Picture of anode interaction with electron beam created by me]

The interaction not the electrons with the anode creates x-rays. This diagram indicates however, that there are no x-rays transmitted outside of the field limit, indicating some sort of law of reflection for the interaction of electrons with metals. Is this diagram correct or will x-rays be (as I would intuitively guess) be emitted in all directions from the metal surface. Please can you explain either way.

Comment: I found this presentation online
http://www.tc.umn.edu/~watan016/Production_of_x-rays_RTT.pdf

Check slide 7, apparently there is an angular distribution of photons.